# CoreData MultiThreading Delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my iPad application, I am using Multithreading to read data from my database and hence I am using different manged object contexts as explained [Fred McCann's blog](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/)

The problem I am facing is while deleting items from the database. When I try to delete, I get the error that the managedObjectContext cannot delete another objectContext's data. How do I solve this problem?

It would be great is someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `objectId`s around and then get that object from the other context.

```
NSManagedObject *object = // get the object...
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = object.objectID;
// Pass to other context on other thread...
// ...
NSManagedObject *sameObjectDifferentContext = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:objectID]
```